# Getting google.sqladmin not a function error

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

I am using `GAE` to deploy my project. I am trying to use this instances export function [mysql-admin v1beta4](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/export) to take a backup of my `Cloud SQL` database to a `GCS` bucket. I am trying to use the code they have mentioned on their site.
 After doing `npm install --save googleapis` I am trying to require these

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var sqlAdmin = google.sqladmin('v1beta4');
```

But I am getting this error

```
TypeError: google.sqladmin is not a function
```

Is there any deprecated package issue or something?

Comment: Have you already enabled the Cloud SQL Administration API at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sqladmin?

Comment: yes, I did that. The issue was with importing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a breaking change in a recent version of the library, and the import now looks like this:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
```

See the [library source](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client#google-apis) for more examples.